# How to input Date with slider in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I have a concept with a slider, where each shift of the slider will change the date value.

I would like it to act as following:

If `value = 1` Then `Day + 1` (tomorrow)
If `value = 2` Then `Day + 2` (day after tomorrow)

Thanks In Advance.

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input onchange='setImage(this)' type="range" min="0" max="8" value="0" step="1" id="myRange" class="slider" />
  <p class="text-slider"> <b>Value : <span id="demo"> </span> (<span id="Date"> </span>)</b></p>
</div>
<script>
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var yy = date.getYear();
  var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
  document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML = day + ' ' + months + ' ' + year;
  var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = document.getElementById("demo");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  slider.oninput = function () {
    if (value > 1) { (id = "Date", day + 1) }
    else { }
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: when using the slider, the value does not change which should be adjusted to the date

Comment: slider.oninput = function () {
    if (value > 1) { (id = "Date", day + 1) }
    else { }
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }

Comment: I've left a snippet below, let me know if you have any questions about it. It should do what you're looking for. I've tried to explain what was missing in your original code.

Comment: Please edit the post, don't add code to the comment thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get the value in the slider and then add that value to the day as you slide it. Also, you should check if the value is greater or equal to zero so that when you slide back to zero it gets back to the current date. Furthermore, you'll have to parse the value that you get from the slider input, as it's a string and in order to add it to the day you'll need it to be a number. See the snippet below:

```js
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = yy < 1000 ? yy + 1900 : yy;

var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var date = document.getElementById("Date");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
date.innerHTML = day + " " + month + " " + year;
slider.oninput = function(e) {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if (value >= 0) {
    date.innerHTML = day + value + " " + month + " " + year;
  } else {}
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input onchange="setImage(this)" type="range" min="0" max="8" value="0" step="1" id="myRange" class="slider" />
  <p class="text-slider">
    <b>Value : <span id="demo"> </span> (<span id="Date"> </span>)</b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you change, when after the 30 or 31 you should move to the next month and become the date 1 ? So it's not the date 32, 33 . . . .